# SeekBarPreference seekBarIncrement

Tags: android, increment, seekbar

I want to set `seekBarIncrement` in an xml (rather than programmatically). I have tried many variants of adding it to my xml, including in a style, as `seekBarIncrement="100"`, `asp:seekBarIncrement="100"` etc. Nothing breaks/complains, but there is no increment either --- the seekbar values all differ only by 1, not 100, and if I put a log in code, it hasn't seen any increase there either.

How do I get `seekBarIncrement` to take effect? I'm using `android.support.v7.preference.SeekBarPreference`.

(I extended the class and do see its value, it just doesn't show anywhere or seem to affect anything)

For reference, the Support Library defines the following:

```
<declare-styleable name="SeekBarPreference">
    <attr format="integer" name="min"/>
    <attr name="android:max"/>
    <attr name="android:layout"/>
    <attr format="integer" name="seekBarIncrement"/>
    <attr format="boolean" name="adjustable"/>
    <attr format="boolean" name="showSeekBarValue"/>
</declare-styleable>
```

which one can see set in the `SeekBarPreference` class itself:

```
TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(
            attrs, R.styleable.SeekBarPreference, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);

    mMin = a.getInt(R.styleable.SeekBarPreference_min, 0);
    setMax(a.getInt(R.styleable.SeekBarPreference_android_max, 100));
    setSeekBarIncrement(a.getInt(R.styleable.SeekBarPreference_seekBarIncrement, 0));
    mAdjustable = a.getBoolean(R.styleable.SeekBarPreference_adjustable, true);
    mShowSeekBarValue = a.getBoolean(R.styleable.SeekBarPreference_showSeekBarValue, true);
```

Answer (score 1):

I added some math to `OnPreferenceChangeListener` that uses the defined increment to round the value properly.

```
@Override
public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
    final String key = preference.getKey();
    if (key.equals(getString(R.string.key_scanning_delay))) {
        final SeekBarPreference sbp = (SeekBarPreference) preference;
        final int increment = sbp.getSeekBarIncrement();
        float value = (int) newValue;
        final int rounded = Math.round(value / increment);
        final int finalValue = rounded * increment;
        if (finalValue == value) return true;
        else sbp.setValue(finalValue);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

I'm using `androidx.preference.SeekBarPreference`, but there is probably little to no differences between these two libraries.

So, first check that it's the right preference. Then do the math. If the new calculated value is the same as the value the method was called with, `return true` so the value will be persisted. Most likely the values will differ on the first go. In that case, call the preference's `setValue` method again to update the view (and the value label if used). This time no math is needed (obviously) so it will `return true` and the value will be persisted. Finally `return false` so the original uncorrected value will be discarded.

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation, the only xml attribute mentioned is `android:thumb` so what you're trying to do doesn't seem possible.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SeekBar

I'd suggest going with either a programmatic approach or you could implement your own ViewGroup which accepts a parameter like seekBarIncrement and then passes it to the SeekBarPreference.

Comment: Actually, the Support Library defines attributes which the SeekBarPreference class then calls (I've added this info to my question) and these attributes include `seekBarIncrement`. The issue seems it doesn't appear to actually do anything or at least has no impact on my seekbar.

Comment: Upon further research, documentation indicates it affects only arrow keys (though I'm not sure what an arrow key is on a seekbar?) but I need it to impact the bar itself. :/

Comment: Can you try setting it with `app:seekBarIncrement`? I'm not sure if your question has a typo there

Comment: Thank you, I understand `asp` to be a `res_auto` pointer but I tried your suggestion of `app` too. However, it doesn't seem to impact the bar still